# Map Zoom Issue on Back Button Press

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, dictionary, bing-maps, bing

I've got this weird problem thats been really frustrating me. I've got a map control on a view. The map view page is called using a button from the main page. Ive bound the Maps Zoom property to a zoom property in my view model. When i open the page for the first time, double click on the page, the map zooms in to the next level, e.g. from zoom level 13 to 13.122234 to 14 (calls the set property twice), no problems there (even though i dont really understand why it has to do it in 2 steps). However, if I press the back button, bringing me back to the main page, then click back into the map page, when i double click the map the zoom is all messed up. It zooms in, then seems to zoom back out slighty, then zooms back in a bit, making the zoom look really jerky, plus it doesnt zoom in fully, e.g. goes from 13 to 14 to 13.8.

I dont know whats going on. There seems to be no difference in what code is called between the first and second navigations to the map page, yet the behaviour is different. Obviously there must be some difference in what code is being called but i cant see it. It also seems to call the Zoom Set property 5 or 6 times each time i try to zoom in after Ive pressed back button then gone back to the page again!!? does anyone have any detailed info on how the map zoom property functions and any idea on why its malfunctioning after i press the back button? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've experienced the same zoom problems before. In my case, the issue was with the zoom property being bound to two different maps inadvertently because of page navigation. Make sure you aren't creating a new map each time you navigate to the page and then binding the `ZoomLevel` to the same property.

A way to guarantee that it doesn't happen is to unbind the the `Zoomlevel` property when you leave the page with the map and then rebind it when you navigate back to it. Though this isn't very good coding practice...

Comment: Hi Bryan, ya I'll have a look into that and let you know, I think you might be right. That seems like a bit of a bug! surprised more people dont mention the issue. But is probably more down to me not having a good enough understanding of how the back button effects my pages.